# Delete array item if match another array item

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two array.

first array store in $array1;

```
Array
(
    [status] => 0
    [message] => Already In List
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => sazib
                    [list_status] => sync
                    [item_list] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [name] => item1
                                    [picture] => 1409220406-apple.png
                                    [purchase_status] => no
                                    [total_quantity] => 7
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [name] => item1
                                    [picture] => 
                                    [purchase_status] => no
                                    [total_quantity] => 3
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [name] => item1
                                    [picture] => 
                                    [purchase_status] => no
                                    [total_quantity] => 3
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 5
                                    [name] => item1
                                    [picture] => 
                                    [purchase_status] => no
                                    [total_quantity] => 4
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 6
                                    [name] => item1
                                    [picture] => 
                                    [purchase_status] => no
                                    [total_quantity] => 4
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 37
                                    [name] => item1
                                    [picture] => 
                                    [purchase_status] => no
                                    [total_quantity] => 4
                                )


                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => sazib
                    [list_status] => sync
                    [item_list] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 10
                                    [name] => test
                                    [picture] => 
                                    [purchase_status] => no
                                    [total_quantity] => 3
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 11
                                    [name] => prime
                                    [picture] => 
                                    [purchase_status] => no
                                    [total_quantity] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

second array store in $array2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [list_id] => 1
            [item_id] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [list_id] => 1
            [item_id] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [list_id] => 3
            [item_id] => 11
        )

)
```

now if first array compare with second array.depend on given example

here first array first index id 1 match with second array [0] and [1] so from first array this list item will be deleted .also other like same.

after calculation output will be

```
Array
(
    [status] => 0
    [message] => Already In List
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => sazib
                    [list_status] => sync
                    [item_list] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [name] => item1
                                    [picture] => 1409220406-apple.png
                                    [purchase_status] => no
                                    [total_quantity] => 7
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [name] => item1
                                    [picture] => 
                                    [purchase_status] => no
                                    [total_quantity] => 3
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [name] => item1
                                    [picture] => 
                                    [purchase_status] => no
                                    [total_quantity] => 3
                                )



                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 6
                                    [name] => item1
                                    [picture] => 
                                    [purchase_status] => no
                                    [total_quantity] => 4
                                )



                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => sazib
                    [list_status] => sync
                    [item_list] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 10
                                    [name] => test
                                    [picture] => 
                                    [purchase_status] => no
                                    [total_quantity] => 3
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I am confused how can i calculate it.

I want if any list_id($array2) match with first array checking every item [id] then delete ($array1)  [item_list] array item match with [item_id] corresponding [list_id] () from matched item [id] of first array.

Please compare my given expected result array with given $array1 and $array2

Comment: Please say what you want more simply. I can't really figure out what you want.

Comment: I cannot figure out what exactly your criteria is. Could you provide something like: This element should be in my final output because `$array1['result'][0]['item_list'][0]['id'] == $array2[0]['item_id']`?
Anyhow: You should maybe reconsider your array structure as it is quite confusing.

Comment: This looks like something for a database so that you can query data rather than working with awkwardly sized arrays.